# How to get an array of all selected values of all dropdownlists in div

Tags: jquery, html, select, selector

Here's what I'm trying to parse with jQuery:

```
<tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>abc@abc.com</td>
    <td>asdfasdf asdfasdf</td>
    <td>
        <div class="roleoption">
            <img src="/Public/images/delete.png" alt="delete" />
            <select id="role" name="role">
                <option value="1">Anonimo</option>
                <option value="2">Registrado</option>
                <option value="3">Tecnico</option>
                <option value="4">Empresario</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="5">Editor</option>
                <option value="6">Financias</option>
                <option value="7">Administrador</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <img class="add-role" src="/Public/images/add.png" alt="add" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

And the javascript code:

```
             select  td       tr       get the first td's value?
var userId = $(this).parent().parent().select
```

That's just for getting the user id, I can't seem to figure out how to select elements.

Then I need to grab each .val() of every `select` inside the td. Something like:

```
$(this).parent().find('select').each().val();??
```

How can I wrap this code up and return something like:

```
//Save array of values: { user: 4, roles { rol: 1, rol: 3, rol: 6 } }
```

I intend to use this array of values in an ajax request.

Comment: Can you post the HTML that's been generated, not the server side code that generates it?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Edited with actual HTML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var selectValues = new Array();
$('div.roleoption').find('select').each(function() {
    selectValues.push($(this).val());
}
```

There's probably a much better way of doing the same thing in jQuery, but that should work.

Comment: That's great, except it'll grab every single select value in every single roleoption. I need to grab only the val within the parent().parent() (ie the td the selectoption is in).

Comment: Can I chain selectors: `$(this).parent().parent().allselectitemshere`.

Comment: When are you planning on calling this? As the result of an event such as clicking on a specific element? You're using `this` in your code snippets, but I'm not really sure what you're expecting `this` to be.

Comment: I just simplified the code so the question was clearer. `$(this)` is the select element, which is what I was going for. Thanks. :)

Comment: You forget to complete bracket of each @Anthony Grist

Comment: var selectValues = new Array();
$('div.roleoption').find('select').each(function() {
    selectValues.push($(this).val());
});   Here is correct format

Answer (score -1):

a select element with the multiple attribute set

```
<select id="role" name="role" multiple="multiple">


$(function () {
     $('#role').val();
});
```